# how to fetch two records with reference to single table using foreign key in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am a beginner to Laravel. I am trying to display all table records based on the foreign key. The problem I am facing is that my Travel_offering table has two columns beginning_location and Ending_location both are foreign key referenced to location table I want to retrieve both records. I know about relationships i.e belongs to and has many. but I am not able to do it for multiple columns referenced to the single table

**travel_offerings  table**

```
class CreateTravelOfferingsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('travel_offerings', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('begning_location')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('dest_location')->unsigned();
            $table->time('leaving_time');
            $table->date('leaving_date');
            $table->float('offering_price');
            $table->boolean('active');
            $table->timestamps();

        });

        Schema::table('travel_offerings',function (Blueprint $table){

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('begning_location')->references('id')->on('locations');
            $table->foreign('dest_location')->references('id')->on('locations');

        });

    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('travel_offerings');
    }

}
```

**locations table**

```
class CreateLocationsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('location_spot');
            $table->string('location_town');
            $table->string('location_city');
            $table->float('location_latitude');
            $table->float('location_longitude');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('locations');
    }
}
```

**locations model**

```
class locations extends Model
{
    function location()
    {
        //what should I write here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create two relations one for each of them. Then you can fetch them by saying: `Location::with('dist1','dist2')->get()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the relations of locations model with another model inside locations.php
for example, if your location model has one to one relation with TravelOffering model your model file should be like

```
class locations extends Model
{
    function travel_offering ()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\TravelOffering','foreign_key', 'local_key');
    }
}
```

You can define multiple relation here. Take a look into laravel relation [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships). By defining relation , you can retrive value based on the relation which means you no need to write a nested query anymore. 
if you have eloquent resultset of locations model you can also get TravelOffering too.

```
$a = locations::find(1);
$TravelOffering = $a->travel_offering;
```

*you should name your model with capitalized singular words and foreign key be like parent_table_name_id because Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. If you do so, don't have to specify the foreign key in relation